# encrypting a url parameter in php and sending it via mail. And decrypting on the other end

Tags: php, url, encryption

I want to send a link via mail with the receiver's name as an encrypted parameter in the link, eg:

```
www.xyz.com?key=ghYGhbDKuSbnklS876BSjug
```

Where `ghYGhbDKuSbnklS876BSjug` is the encrypted name. When the receiver clicks the link, it'll open up on a page and the name will be decrypted there.

```
$key = $_POST['key'];
$val = decrypt($key);
echo $val;
```

I've tried many encryption description techniques. none seem to work. One did, but it isn't decrypting all names.

Comment: Try `mcrypt_encrypt()` function of PHP

Comment: is there an equivalent decrypt function?

Comment: I realized the error in some techniques are that it has '+' characters. And while using $_GET['key'], the '+' is converted to spaces. that's why decryption isn't working properly.

So any techniques that don't have characters?Just numbers and letters?

Comment: You can use base64_encode & base64_decode  of PHP.

Comment: If this is going from the same server to the same server, why don't you just send a meaningless id and look up the name by id from your database? You don't actually need to send the name value itself, just something that you can look it up by.

Comment: No! cz each mail would send a diff name based on who it's sending to. And the user will click on the link to see a html page with his name decrypted there!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to further convert my encrypted string to alphanumeric code. FInally its working!

```
function hex_encode($input) {
    return bin2hex($input);
}

function hex_decode($input) {
    return pack("H*", $input);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I still got to wait for 18 hours! :)